# Error messages not showing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to show some login validation errors using the code below but it's not working.
When i click on Login button it's going to the next page and error messages are not displayed as supposed.
Any ideas?

### index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="angularFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<form action="next.html" ng-submit="fun1($event)">
userName:<input name="name" ng-model="un">
<div style="color: red">{{msg1}}</div><br>
passWord:<input type="password" name="pwd" ng-model="pw">
<div style="color: red">{{msg2}}</div><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</body>
</html>
```

### angularFile.js:

```
var app = angular.modul("demoApp",[]);

app.controller("Ctrl",function($scope){

    $scope.un="";
    $scope.pw="";
    $scope.msg1="";
    $scope.msg2="";
    $scope.fun1=function(e){

        if($scope.un.leggth==0){
            $scope.msg1="please enter user name"
                e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            $scope.msg1="";
        }

        if($scope.pw.leggth==0){
            $scope.msg2="please enter password"
                e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            $scope.msg2="";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You have misspelt length.

Comment: `length` instead `leggth`

Comment: Is Tag 'java' correct or did you mean Javascript'?

Comment: and misspelled `module`.

Comment: check your dev tools for any errors.

Comment: i used length instead leggth but still no use

Comment: I am confused about where i did mi-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module("demoApp",[]);

app.controller("Ctrl",function($scope){

    $scope.un="";
    $scope.pw="";
    $scope.msg1="";
    $scope.msg2="";
    $scope.fun1=function(e){

        if($scope.un.length == 0){
            $scope.msg1="please enter user name"
                e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            $scope.msg1="";
        }

        if($scope.pw.length== 0){
            $scope.msg2="please enter password"
                e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            $scope.msg2="";
        }
    }
});
```

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UAX6KUbq5PPx4g2BR1Zq?p=preview)

Use this code and let me know.

make sure you have imported the library correctly or import it from web

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/a‌​ngular.min.js"></scr‌​ipt>
```

Comment: by default its showing error messages like--->{{msg1}},{{msg2}} with out tapped on login button when tapped on button then move to next page

Comment: see the plunker

Comment: see on console what error is there? have you imported library correctly?

Comment: @Krish i believe you have not imported the js file correctly use this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: yes but what is problem in my code i just copied and paste your code also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162346/discussion-between-aman-and-krish).

Comment: problem was your importing lib
and length keyword
if i have solved you ques please accept it

Answer (score 0):

You have not close your form tag in html. and all other things that other developers are suggesting.

```
 <div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <form ng-submit="fun1($event)">
    userName:<input name="name" ng-model="un">
    <div style="color: red">{{msg1}}</div><br>
    passWord:<input type="password" name="pwd" ng-model="pw">
    <div style="color: red">{{msg2}}</div><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Inside Controller--

```
var app = angular.module("demoApp",[]);

app.controller("Ctrl",function($scope){

    $scope.un="";
    $scope.pw="";
    $scope.msg1="";
    $scope.msg2="";
    $scope.fun1=function(e){

        if($scope.un.length==0){
            $scope.msg1="please enter user name"
                e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            $scope.msg1="";
        }

        if($scope.pw.length==0){
            $scope.msg2="please enter password"
                e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            $scope.msg2="";
        }
    }
});
```

Working jsfiddle link--
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vikasguptaa9/sW2V9/61/)

Answer (score 0):

It's `angular.module();`

You have put it as `angular.modul()`

```
var app = angular.module("demoApp", []);
```

Also fix the spellings in `$scope.pw.leggth` and `$scope.un.leggth` to `length`

You need to fix these and it will work.